# in R write.csv but include only specific columns

Tags: r, csv, gps

I have large data.frame. The structure is like this:

```
   user  DateTime            Longitude Latitude
   <chr> <chr>               <chr>     <chr>   
 1 1000 2018-04-16_09-31-43 8.1       40.1
 2 1001 NA                  8.12      40.11
 3 1002 NA                  8.11      40.05
 4 1003 2018-04-16_09-31-34 8.13      40.11
 5 1004 2018-04-16_09-31-44 NA        NA
```

There are multiple users and I want a csv-file for each user.

```
users <- split(gpsData, gpsData$user)
lapply(users, function(x) write.csv(x, file=paste0("./root/", x[1,"user"], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

This works really good. But I want to drop the user column. Is there a way that I can save several csv-files by user but drop this column while saving the csv-files?

```
   DateTime            Longitude Latitude
   NA                  12        40
   NA                  13.2      41      
   2018-04-23_07-21-13 3.4       31.5
```

Thx for your help!

PS: I have to handle over 100 mio data points. If there is a faster way to do it, let me know!

Comment: If user is the first column, inside your `lapply` change `write.csv(x, ...)` to `write.csv(x[-1], ...)`.

Comment: As for doing things faster, `write.csv` is a little slow. `readr::write_csv` or especially `data.table::fwrite` will be much faster.

Comment: thx for your help! It worked. I will try it wwith data.table::fwrite